# Firefox - displaying web notifications from extension/addon

Tags: javascript, notifications, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm building Firefox addon (with addon-SDK) and I'd like to display desktop notification to a user. 
There is [Notification object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) but it doesn't seem to work from addon code (background page). There is no error etc, but no dialog for permissions is displayed, so no notifications can be displayed. I've tried of course adding permissions/desktop-notifications but no effect.

Edit: pasting sample code I've tried (the code is located inside callback function for socket.io event. Event is received properly, but no notification is displayed, or request for permission.

```
        Notification.requestPermission( function(status) {
        console.log(status); // notifications will only be displayed if "granted"
        var n = new Notification("title", {body: "notification body"}); // this also shows the notification
    });
```

I've also found [alerts service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/User_Notifications_and_Alerts) this one works. However alerts disappear quite fast (too fast for me)  - edit: that's the way it works - so guess no code sample needed, as I don't see any option to make them last longer.

Is there any way to display chrome like notifications on Firefox? (chrome.notifications.create) Or at least use web notifications object from within the addon?

Comment: What have you tried already? Include some code in the question and it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: I've edited my original question like @ArtOfCode suggested but I don't think the code sample has a real meaning here since it's quite default from docs works on webpages, doesn't work with addons. Not sure if I can be any clearer about that.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [Firefox addon docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Add-ons/SDK), specifically [Display a Popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Display_a_Popup)

Comment: Thanks. Seen that but panels disappear after clicking any other place. So if plugin displays such popup to user while he's actively browsing he might not even see it (I don't  want it to be to intrusive for user - displaying panels on center of browser probably won't be too good idea). So looks like there is no other solution? Display alerts which disappear very quickly or display popups which might disappear if user is clicking somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the add-on SDK, you're looking at the wrong docs. Here are the [notification docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/notifications).

You create a notification like so:

```
var notifications = require("sdk/notifications");
notifications.notify({
  title: "Jabberwocky",
  text: "'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves",
  data: "did gyre and gimble in the wabe",
  onClick: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

All the docs you look at should be a subset of [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK).

Comment: One more question - perhaps you would know that. What's the proper way to invoking multiple notifications? calling notifications.notify() line by line causes that no notification is displayed. And I'm getting only errors "###!!! [Child][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: Route error: message sent to unknown actor ID" which googling gives no explanation. Not sure if this some protection against multiple notifications?

Comment: @gemini On top of Googling, you should search through the MDN link I already provided and StackOverflow. Look at [the second search result](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=notifications+[firefox-addon-sdk]) here.

Also, it's best practice to start a new question rather than follow up in the comments if you have a new question.

Comment: Thanks for clarification and pointing out search result. Looks like  local search here gives better results then Google.